# How to add header to a new cms page without top menu?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a cms page. I want add header without top menu.

I tried copying **header.phtml content without topmenu content** to new cms page layout and excluded header link. It did not work.

PS - Layout of new cms page is also custom. I have also created a layout for my new cms page.

PS - There are 2 divs in **header.phtml**. On copying 1st div is working while 2nd is not.
2nd div content has banner block, cart block and a custom block.
Apart from theses 2 div **header.phtml** also contain php code for **topmenu** i.e.

```
      <?php    echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

which I am excluding while copying and pasting.

I am using magento 1.7.0.2

Any suggestion for this or is there an another way to do this?

Comment: Are you using any theme too?

Comment: Yes I am using a theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open app>design>frontend>default>your_theme>layout>page.xml in editor.

There is a block name="header". In that there is a block for topmenu say name="menu".

Copy name and open admin>cms>your_cms_page>Design.

In Layout Update XML write

```
<remove name="menu" />
```

Save and refresh the browser.

Comment: I have taken [name="menu"] as example.

Answer (score 1):

In the back-end, in the page where you edit the CMS-page details under the tab "Design" find the "Custom XML Update" input field and add there:

```
<remove name="top.menu" />
```

This will make Magento ignore the block called "top.menu" in your CMS page

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. I have also created new Layout for CMS page. Also I have edited some part of the question. You might check that too.

Comment: Try `<remove name="topMenu" />`. I missed that the block is called 'topMenu', not 'top.menu'

Comment: Thats what I did in first time.

Comment: There is another block, which outputs the top nav for the cms pages. Try removing "hp_nav": `<remove name="hp_nav" />`

Comment: Where? Is it in admin panel or files of magento?